# "arrange by date created" doesn't work

Tags: finder

I'm trying to order old folders and old files using "arrange by date created" from the View menu, but that choice is greyed out. How do I do this, and why doesn't it want to allow me to do this?

I'm running OS 10.6.8 on an iMac.

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the Date Created column displaying in Finder, for that option to be available.
In the View menu, select Show View Options, then tick the Date Created box.  If you have a Finder window open, you'll see that column pop into view. (If you haven't, it will be shown in subsequent Finder windows).

After that, the Arrange By > Date Created option should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem... The Date Created box in View Options cannot be selected....

I did find this link
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009083113534843

Haven't tried it as don't have that software...

Crazy that this has to be added....

Good luck!